# Date diff minutes not lining up with hour php

Tags: php, datetime

Right now the difference between the time-stamp and time() is about an hour.

I am having a weird issue where if I echo the minutes I get a low number like `4` which is incorrect.

If I echo the hours I get the correct amount which is `1` as well as getting `0` for days. I am not sure why the minutes is not showing correctly.

```
$ticket_resolve = '1496264673';

$date1_find_days_resolve = new DateTime(date("Y-m-dTH:i:s",time()));
$date2_find_days_resolve = new DateTime(date("Y-m-dTH:i:s",$ticket_resolve));
$diff_resolve = $date2_find_days_resolve->diff($date1_find_days_resolve);
$mins_first_resolve = $diff_resolve->format('%i');
$hours_first_resolve = $diff_resolve->format('%h');
$days_first_resolve = $diff_resolve->format('%a');
```

Comment: i am getting correct output like 16,1,0

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. https://3v4l.org/nFhV8 - I get the correct values; as commented in the demo (1hr 19 mins difference).

Comment: So what do you expect for the minutes? "About an hour" difference, and your hours is `1`, so I'd expect a low value for minutes... if it was about 2 hours difference, and hours was `1`, then I'd expect a high value for minutes

Comment: Right now when I echo the minutes I get `25` but the time difference right now is 1 hour and 25 minutes. I should be seeing a much larger number.

Comment: I should be seeing `85` minutes

Comment: If the difference is `1:25`, then you should be getting `25` for the minutes... it isn't  total number of minutes between the times, the minutes value will be between 0 and 59: to get `85`, multiply hours * 60 + minutes,

Comment: so you want it to show 85 min for 1 hour 25 min? then convert hour to minute

Comment: Oh I see......I need the full amount of minutes, the code is providing the minutes of the total amount. I need to add 60 for the hour to the minutes to get the full 85 minutes. Im an idiot.... sorry guys. I was misunderstanding the output. I hate TimeDiff's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert hour to minute for desired output like below:-

```
<?php

$ticket_resolve = '1496264673';

$date1_find_days_resolve = new DateTime(date("Y-m-dTH:i:s",time()));
$date2_find_days_resolve = new DateTime(date("Y-m-dTH:i:s",$ticket_resolve));
$diff_resolve = $date2_find_days_resolve->diff($date1_find_days_resolve);
$mins_first_resolve = $diff_resolve->format('%i');
$hours_first_resolve = $diff_resolve->format('%h');


$days_first_resolve = $diff_resolve->format('%a');

echo $total_minutes = $hours_first_resolve*60+$mins_first_resolve;
```

Output:- https://eval.in/809143

Note:- to convert days also you can do `$days_first_resolve*24*60`

Comment: Yeah I was misunderstanding the output of my code, I get it now.

Comment: @CesarBielich  glad to help you. Please check the note section too.